# Is it possible to auto generate dimens with ratio?

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin

I have an application. All sizes I put in values-sw330dp/dimens.xml. Also I have values-sw266dp/dimens.xml where I put same items but with 0.8 ratio. It working well for me and here is no problems.

Is it possible to automate this work? I want to fill values only in values-sw330dp/dimens.xml and when I build project Gradle would generate values-sw266dp/dimens.xml with specified ratio.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate dimens values automatically for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi using a marvelous tool called [dimenify](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9349-dimenify), in where you will enter only any value and with a `right-click` --> `generate` will be able to generate all the other values you want automatically, and using the same aspect ration used you can provide the tablet dimens also.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your Layout widget width as `match_parent` and height as `wrap_content`. then define some global ratio param.

then programmatic do something like:

```
layoutView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(
            new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutChange (View v,
                                            int left,
                                            int top,
                                            int right,
                                            int bottom,
                                            int oldLeft,
                                            int oldTop,
                                            int oldRight,
                                            int oldBottom) {


                   viewHeightPixel = (int) (layoutView.getWidth() / VIEW_RATIO);
                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
                   lp = layoutView.getLayoutParams();
                   if (lp.height != viewHeightPixel ) {
                       lp.height = viewHeightPixel ;
                       layoutView.setLayoutParams(lp);
                   }

                    layoutView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

                }
            }
    );
```

This way you are not "binding" your views to a specific height / width which will make your life difficult when changing ratios / dimension